# How to draw arrows of certain length from a point, at a certain angle?

Tags: geometry, code-request, graphics

What's the specification to draw arrows of a certain length (from a reference point), at a given angle?

Say, I want to draw an arrow of length 1 at 0 degrees, and one of length 0.5 at 90 degrees, each arrow starting at a giving `originPt`. Ideally, I'd like a function where I give as argument a list of `arrowSpecs`, like this:

```
(*Arrow list {arrowColor, originPt, lengthFromOrigin, angle}*)
originPt = {0,0};
arrowSpecs = {{Blue,originPt,1,0},{Red,originPt,0.5,90}}

(*My desired function*)
arrowDrawing[arrowSpecs]
```

Getting this:

[image]

Note that the `originPt` could be different for every arrow, here just for simplicity I used the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
originPt = {0, 0};
arrowSpecs = {{Blue, originPt, 1, 0}, {Red, originPt, 0.5, 90 Degree}};

arrowDrawing[specs_] := 
 Graphics[{Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.1], #[[1]], 
     Arrow[{#[[2]], #[[2]] + {#[[3]] Cos[#[[4]]], #[[3]] Sin[#[[4]]]}}]} & /@ 
   specs]

arrowDrawing[arrowSpecs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the usage of `Degree` when defining the angle.

Comment: If we test with `originPt = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2]`, what happens if originPt is not (0, 0)? Does `Arrow[{#[[2]], {#[[3]] Cos[#[[4]]], #[[3]] Sin[#[[4]]]} + #[[2]]}]} & /@  specs` solve the problem?

Comment: @creidhne, yes, sorry, I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the function [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath) for this purpose:

```
toArrow[{color_, orig_, len_, angle_}] := {
    color, 
    Arrow @ AnglePath[orig, {{len,angle}}]
}
```

For example:

```
arrowSpecs = {{Blue, {1, 1}, 1, 0}, {Red, {-1, -1}, 0.5, 90 Degree}};
Graphics[toArrow /@ arrowSpecs, Axes->True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[transformedArrow]
transformedArrow[{style_, origin_, length_, angle_}] :=
   {style, 
   Arrow @ AffineTransform[{length RotationMatrix @ angle, origin}] @ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}
```

***Examples:***

```
arrowSpecs = {{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Arrowheads[Large], Blue], {1,1}, 1, π/4}, 
 {Red, {-1, 0}, 0.5, 90 Degree}};

Graphics[transformedArrow /@ arrowSpecs]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
aSpecs = Table[{RandomColor[], RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2], 
   RandomReal[{.5, 2}], RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, 20]; 

Graphics[{Thick, transformedArrow /@ aSpecs}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]